# Firebase querying data by two regions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
  "key1" : {
    "region": 2,
    "text": "This is text"
  },
  "key2" : {
    "region": 8,
    "text": "This is text"
  }.
  "key3" : {
    "region": 6,
    "text": "This is text"
  }
}
```

I want to get the JSON objects with a region of 2 and 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a range of regions, meaning all region from `2` to `8`, in which will be also included all regions like (3, 4, 5, 6 and 7), Peter's answer will work perfectly fine.

But if you want to use only region `2` and `8`, I recommend you duplicate data. This is a quite common practice when it comes to Firebase and is called `denormalization` and for that, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA).

When you are duplicating data, there is one thing that need to keep in mind. In the same way you are adding data, you need to maintain it. With other words, if you want to update/detele an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

In your case, you should consider augmenting your data structure to allow a reverse lookup like this:

```
regionTwoAndEight
  |
  --- "key1": true
  |
  --- "key2": true
```

Comment: Thank you! And what is the query to get both 2 and 8 then?

Comment: What do you think about making region a JSON array, that always will have either "region": [2, 8] or "region": [8]

Comment: No, Firebase documentation recommends against using arrays. It is an anti-pattern when it comes to storing data. One of the many reasons Firebase recommends against using arrays is that it makes the security rules impossible to write. So I strongly recommend you use the solution above, using maps.

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Yes it did help me a lot, but I can't still get my head around how to structure it

Comment: Just create this separate node, add only those specific regions and that's it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query q=ref.orderByChild("region").startAt(2).endAt(8);
q.addValueEventListener(..){//..}
```

Assuming the the random keys are direct children to the root node.

Comment: Thank you, but it also gives me region 5 objects and all regions aren't in the right order, for example, it gives me all of region 2, then all of region 5 and then finally all of region 8. is it possible to get the data in the order they're in in the firebase database or do I have to sort the data in my code?